# How can I play midi on this tesla coil?

Tags: high-voltage, high-frequency, resonance, tesla-coil

I've made several small tesla coils, however I wanted to buy one that was compact and powerful, so I bought [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08KDG6CFK) one. I'm assuming it is a drsstc, since it has a half bridge of mosfets or igbts, which switch power to the primary. It is fairly powerful, and can make arcs that jump several inches. It has a bluetooth feature where it can play music, however it doesn't work very well, and only works well using a function generator online. I assume it is some sort of interupter circuit; is it possible to use the midi files that something like the oneTesla uses? Why do drsstc's use midi files instead of just regular mp3's? Can't all music just be made into a square wave?

Comment: MIDI and MP3 are completely different things for different purposes. MIDI is a way of passing instructions on how to pay notes while MP3 is recorded sound.

Comment: `Can't all music just be made into a square wave?` You can make it into a square wave, but if it's polyphonic it may sound really really bad. That's why you'd use MIDI, so you can pick out just the (monophonic) melody line.